# Elastic search java specific configuration

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I try to access a local instance of elasticserach through java api.
According to [elastic search doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/2.0/transport-client.html), I can use the "cluster.name" property to specify the name of the cluster to use. Perfect.
Sadly can't I specify the node name to use? I can see that this one is also configurable in [configuration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/setup-configuration.html).
Maybe it would be a bad practice??
Also, I can see[here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/setup-service-win.html) that I can define a custom service ID which I did, but how to specify it to my java Transport Client?

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of Elasticsearch is to create a cluster of highly available data. Not all nodes contain all the data and not all nodes might be up all the time. If you want to connect to a single node by specifying its name and for some reason that node is down (it was killed, it is being upgraded, it is being re-provisioned, data was wiped to be reindexed, etc), then your client wouldn't be able to run queries and get results.

Instead, if you connect to the cluster, ES will make sure to route your queries to the cluster nodes that are up, whatever the state of certain nodes that might be down. So the best practice is to always connect via the `cluster.name` to get the best out of your ES cluster.

As for the `SERVICE_ID, it's not something you specify in your code, it's simply the name you want to give to the Elasticsearch service when running on Windows.

Comment: Thank you, but knowing that, I dont get the point of specifying the default node name in my elastic search configuration? Should I let ES define its default node name (marvel characters)? In which use case people will use this property if we dont have to use it?

Comment: For the service ID, I thought it allow me to start several instance of ES on one machine and identify them. So I thought my code would specify it to connect to the good instance. If I dont specify this how my ES client know to which instance to connect? Maybe it is the port to which we connect? If I am right on this point there is maybe something I didnt understand until now it's that I let the default "elasticsearch.yml" to configure an instance of different service id. For an ES instance XXX must I create a XXX.yml?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Specifying the node name is only useful to be better able to recognize them. Not everyone knows what Marvel characters are and which nodes they identify.

Comment: Ok thank you, so I dont touch the node name. Concerning the service id, Am I right thinking I must define an yml file according to the service id?

Comment: Ok, I had a misundertood on this point, I think now it is ok : If I want to have several instance of ES on one server, I will have several elasticsearch "Homes" each one having its configuration file so that I define differnet clusterName/ports for each ones.

PS : I dont know why but the "transport.tcp.port" parameter is not specified in ES doc, but is very usefull because it is the one to which we must connect our java client (could be usefull for nexts ;-) )

Comment: Yep, you got it right now. `transport.tcp.port` is defined [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-transport.html#_tcp_transport). Happy searching ;-)